# How do you assign an image specifically in an rng in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

Sorry if the title and this is confusing, just imagine an rng/random number generator and how do you assign an image specifically inside the rng thingies?

```
let rng = ["random stuff number1", "random stuff number 2",]
```

so that's the rng, then how do you assign this image to that random stuff number 1 and another image to random stuff number 2?

Comment: Do you want links to images or do you have them saved? Either way, just put the link of the image if you're using a link or if you have it saved, just put it in

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean randomly choose an image? You can have an array of image urls then generate a random integer as an index to choose an image.

```
const images = ["assets/image1.jpg", assets/image2.jpg", "assets/image3.jpg"]
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)
const randomImage = images[randomIndex]
```